# Как выполнить скрипт с телефона? Гугл таблица

Tags: javascript, email, google-spreadsheet

Есть гугл таблица с почтовыми адресами. Есть скрипт: когда выделяю адрес конкретного человека, нажимаю на кнопку, выполняется скрипт отправки ему письма. (Код скопирован с просторов интернета, мною отредактирован, думаю ошибки есть, но работает - ну, и ладно).

```
function sendEmails() 
{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, 2)

  var data = activeRange.getValues();  

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) 
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0]; 
    var email = row[1]; 
    //var emailReplyTo = "manager@site.com";
    var subject = "Тема письма";
    var body = "Тест, " + name + "! проверка рассылки";       
    // Отправляем письмо
MailApp.sendEmail({to: email, subject: subject, htmlBody: body});
    //записываем значение «Отправлено» в третью колонку
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue("Отправлено");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); <span id="pastemarkerend"> </span>
  }
}
```

С ноутбука работает, а с телефона нет. Но мне нужно, чтобы скрипт работал и с телефона, когда доступа до ноутбука у меня нет. Как это можно сделать? 
Я думала может сделать еще одну колонку, в которую, если введешь слово "Да", то выполнится мой этот скрипт. Но как это сделать? Ничего не могу найти в интернете, не знаю, как правильно загуглить.

Плюс, еще вопрос.

```
sheet.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue("Отправлено");
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы Отправлено было именно в той строке, кому я отправила письмо, а не в первой только?

Или подскажите какие функции погуглить и в каком направлении искать. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Привяжите скрипт к чекбоксу, когда значение true запускаете скрипт, после выполнения меняете значение на false